# strtok_r functionality for collective delimiters

Tags: c, string, strtok

strtok_r splits a string `"abc:;def ;25"` with delimiter `":;"` as `"abc"`, `"def"` and `"25"`

Are there any functions to return as : `"abc"` and `"def ;25"`
i.e., taking the delimiter collectively and not considering them individually?

Thank you.

Comment: There's an answer to this question which may lead you in the right way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867213/does-strtok-work-with-strings-as-the-delimiter

Comment: with delimiter `":; "` for 1st exsample.