# C - Issue splitting string

Tags: c

I'm using `strtok` in the hope of doing something like Php's `explode`.

At first I thought the following was working correctly

```
details = strtok(line,"]:");
```

But after some closer inspection I realised it was using any instance of `]` and `:` to split the string. What I need is for it to only split the string where the two are together - `]:`.

Maybe `strtok` is the wrong function for this? I played around with `str_split` but this didn't work, either through my implementation or unsuitability.

Any help welcome on splitting my string where an occurrence of `]:` is found.

Comment: Check out my function to [split at any string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22832368/2564301).

Comment: @user3121023 strstr() is not sufficient - he wants to split the entire string, not just find the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C "splitting" a string is really a matter of inserting a null terminator (0x00) in the string itself and let a new char* point to the next byte after it.

It's not so obvious how to do it and, more important, there are many ways to do it

Answer (score 1):

strtok is the wrong function to use as it will split on *any* of the characters in the set of delimiters.

I'm not aware of any standard function to do what you want. You might have to  [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867213/does-strtok-work-with-strings-as-the-delimiter).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will check out that link. Btw I didn't downvote you.

Comment: @ThomasRyan Yep, downvoters should be required to provide a reason, though I'm OK that they remain anonymous. They may have a good point to make, even when it's not clear to others.

Comment: @jarmod not my downvote, but fyi the reason is in the button's tooltip: `this answer is not useful`. Person A might find an answer useful while person B might not

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks for the info, I had not noticed that.